# Group permission list with checkbox based on name and action

Tags: php, html-table, grouping

I have set of data permissions on mysql:

```
|=====================|==================|
|      name           |        action    |
|=====================|==================|
|     setting         |         add      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     setting         |         view     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     setting         |         delete   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     task            |         add      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     task            |         delete   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     report          |         view     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and i would like to display the permission on table like example below:

```
|=====================|======================|
|      permission     |  add | view | delete |
|=====================|======================|
|     setting         |  []  |  []  |   []   |
|---------------------|----------------------|
|     task            |  []  |      |   []   |
|---------------------|----------------------|
|     report          |      |  []  |        |
|---------------------|----------------------|
```

Group each row by name and only show the checkbox where the action same as the column header, below is my code so far, but it still show the checkbox even the action is not same as the column header.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>add</th>
    <th>view</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
<?php
$permissionTitles = array();
foreach($permissions as $permission){
    $permissionTitles[] = $permission['name'];
}
foreach(array_unique($permissionTitles) as $permissionTitle){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$permissionTitle."</td>";
  foreach($permissions as $permission){
    if($permission['name'] == $permissionTitle) {
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']."> 
        </td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

$permissions is from database, it is an array :

```
 Array(
  [0] => Array(
     [name] => setting
     [action] => add
  )
  [1] => Array(
     [name] => setting
     [action] => view
  )
 ....
)
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand how your PHP variables are set up, but wouldn't you need an else statement after the if statement that did the following: echo "<td></td>" ?

Comment: hi @Rumple thank you for comment, i add $permissions value, it is an array. should i add the else statement with just empty <td></td> ?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need. BTW, the first loop could be replaced with `permissionTitles = array_unique(array_column($permissions, 'name'));`

Comment: I don't think that just the else statement would work @Barmar since he loops through all of the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it given your current set up, change:

```
foreach(array_unique($permissionTitles) as $permissionTitle){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$permissionTitle."</td>";
  foreach($permissions as $permission){
    if($permission['name'] == $permissionTitle) {
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']."> 
        </td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

To:

```
foreach(array_unique($permissionTitles) as $permissionTitle){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$permissionTitle."</td>";

  $add = false;
  $view = false;
  $delete = false;

  foreach($permissions as $permission){
    if($permission['name'] == $permissionTitle) {
        if($permission['action'] == 'add'){
            $add = true;
        }
        else if($permission['action'] == 'view'){
            $view = true;
        }
        else if($permission['action'] == 'delete'){
            $delete = true;
        }
    }
  }

  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']." checked=".$add."></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']." checked=".$view."></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']." checked=".$delete."></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rumple it's works, i change $add = false to $add = "disabled" and change td to <td><input type='checkbox' value=".$permission['value']." checked=''   ".$add."></td> so it will disabled the checkbox rather than hide the checkbox